# Ant Multiple Property Values with the Same Name

Tags: java, ant, build

I am working on an ant build script. How do i set the two property value with the same name:

```
<property name="java.src.dir" location="src" />
<property name="java.src.dir" location="src/java" />
```

In my application some of the directories are src/java and some are src. I need to make it flexible enough to work on both.

Comment: If two properties have the same name, how would you be able to reference one or the other? If you just need to use them together (for `fileset includes` for example), you can simply append them in a third property. Please provide an example of what you're trying to do with these properties and I will be able to give a full answer.

Comment: What are you expecting `${java.src.dir}` to evaluate to?

Comment: I was trying to evaluate the source folder for the Java classes in Eclipse. Although I wasn't able to figure this one out on how to do it. I managed to get it to work by changing the remaining Java projects to all be structured as /src/java/...